# How to empty all emails data when account deleted?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, storage

My situation is quite simple and I searched the Internet without any solution to my problem. So I decided to give a try here!

I have removed all email accounts (Gmail and Outlook) from my iPhone 5S accounts.

I supposed that it will automatically delete all local emails data. But still, when I check the Mail usage (in Settings > General > Storage usage), it indicates 1GB used, so obviously data are still there and I found no way to erase it.

So my question is simple, considering my situation, how can I free this email storage?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have deleted the Gmail and Outlook accounts, if you preform a restore using iTunes and backups, all the email data will be free and so return available.

**EDIT:** If you want you can also try with some specific application (e.g., [PhoneClean](http://www.imobie.com/phoneclean/?__c=1)) that help to clean the phone. Anyway, before download third part app I think the restore procedure (that is free) can work as well.

Comment: Hi Mattia. Thank you for your answer. I don't really understand how I should proceed. Should I do a backup and then a restore ?

Comment: Yes, you first perform a backup using iTunes and then you perform a restore of the iPhone (again using iTunes). After the restore iTunes will tell you that a backup for your iPhone is available. You select this backup and the restore will be complete. After all this procedure the space occupied from the emails should become available. Obviously all this assuming you first delete the emails account from the iPhone Settings.

Comment: @fabien7474 I extend the answer.

Comment: Thanks Mattia I'll try that and update you on my outcomes